# javascript object.function call through variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, call

I wanna call a function from an object in js

```
var elementId = event.target.id;
var controller = $('#' + elementId).data('controller') + 'Controller';
var action = $('#' + elementId).data('action');
```

this is my data

right call would look like this

```
FilterController.getCurrentFilter('hosts-button');
```

but how do i build it with my variables elementId / controller / action ?

my try

```
controller + '.' + action + '(' + elementId + ')';
```

don't work

thank you very much for help :)

Comment: `eval(controller + '.' + action + '(' + elementId + ')');`, but that is not recommended

Comment: You're just building a String. You would need to `eval` it to see any action. However, from a security (and app design) point of view, that's generally a very bad idea.

Comment: eval( controller + '.' + action + '(' + elementId + ')' ) ; ???

Comment: There is no need for eval!

Comment: @epascarello so what do you propose me to do ? thank you for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bracket notation will work ass long as it is in window/global scope.

```
window[controller][action](elementId);
```

If it is not in window/gloabl scope, you will need an object that holds the first level. [In reality that is a better solution]

Comment: thanks it works! it is in window scope